Return value of sqlExceptionHelper() is null
I was trying my hands on running my Spring Boot application with MySQL database on Docker Desktop via docker compose. I am getting this error upon running docker compose up .
app-1      | java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(java.sql.SQLException, String)" because the return value of "org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.sqlExceptionHelper()" is null
app-1      |    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:116) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
app-1      |    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentUsingJdbcMetadata(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:290) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]

app-1      |    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
app-1      |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:91) ~[AuthAPI-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
app-1      |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:53) ~[AuthAPI-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
app-1      |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58) ~[AuthAPI-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
app-1      |
app-1      | 2024-07-19T09:13:48.297Z  WARN 1 --- [AuthAPI] [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000025: MySQLDialect does not need to be specified explicitly using 'hibernate.dialect' (remove the property setting and it will be selected by default)
app-1      | 2024-07-19T09:13:53.120Z  INFO 1 --- [AuthAPI] [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
app-1      | 2024-07-19T09:13:53.164Z  INFO 1 --- [AuthAPI] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
app-1      | 2024-07-19T09:13:54.169Z  WARN 1 --- [AuthAPI] [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
app-1      | 2024-07-19T09:13:54.169Z ERROR 1 --- [AuthAPI] [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Communications link failure        
app-1      |
app-1      | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
app-1      | 2024-07-19T09:13:54.511Z ERROR 1 --- [AuthAPI] [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityMana
gerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [Communications link failure
app-1      |
app-1      | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.] [n/a]        
app-1      | 2024-07-19T09:13:54.516Z ERROR 1 --- [AuthAPI] [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exce
ption: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'jwtFilter': Unsatisfied dependency expresse
d through field 'userDetailsService': Error creating bean with name 'customUserDetailsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userReposito
ry': Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.yourengineerbro.AuthAPI.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories decla
red on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManager'
app-1      | 2024-07-19T09:13:54.637Z  INFO 1 --- [AuthAPI] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
app-1      | 2024-07-19T09:13:55.129Z  WARN 1 --- [AuthAPI] [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server
app-1      | 2024-07-19T09:13:55.151Z  INFO 1 --- [AuthAPI] [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 
app-1      |
app-1      | Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
app-1      | 2024-07-19T09:13:55.228Z ERROR 1 --- [AuthAPI] [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
app-1      |
app-1      | org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server
app-1      |    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:165) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar!/:3.3.1]

app-1      |    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:188) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar!/:3.3.1]
app-1      |    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar!/:3.3.1]
app-1      |    ... 15 common frames omitted
app-1      | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtFilter': Unsatisfied dependency 
expressed through field 'userDetailsService': Error creating bean with name 'customUserDetailsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'user
Repository': Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.yourengineerbro.AuthAPI.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositori
es declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManager'

app-1      |    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:128) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar!/:3.3.1]       
app-1      |    ... 20 common frames omitted
app-1      | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customUserDetailsService': Unsatisf
ied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository': Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.yourengineerbro.AuthAPI.repository.Us
erRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManager'

app-1      |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar!/:6.1.10]
app-1      |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:784) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar!/:6.1.10]
app-1      |    ... 62 common frames omitted
app-1      | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.yourengineerb
ro.AuthAPI.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManager'

app-1      |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar!/:6.1.10]
app-1      |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:784) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar!/:6.1.10]
app-1      |    ... 76 common frames omitted
app-1      | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument

app-1      |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar!/:6.1.10]
app-1      |    ... 89 common frames omitted
app-1      | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path 
resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [Communications link failure      

app-1      |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar!/:6.1.10]
app-1      |    ... 101 common frames omitted
app-1      | Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [Communications link failure
app-1      |
app-1      | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.] [n/a]        
app-1      |    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar!/:6.1.10]
app-1      |    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar!/:6.1.10]
app-1      |    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar!/:6.1.10]
app-1      |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1835) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar!/:6.1.10]
app-1      |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar!/:6.1.10]
app-1      |    ... 108 common frames omitted
app-1      | Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [Communications link failure      
app-1      |
app-1      | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.] [n/a]        
app-1      |    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]

app-1      |    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar!/:6.1.10]
app-1      |    ... 112 common frames omitted
app-1      | Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
app-1      |
app-1      | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
app-1      |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:175) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]

com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:150) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
app-1      |    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:166) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
app-1      |    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
app-1      |    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:121) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
app-1      |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:945) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
app-1      |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:815) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
app-1      |    ... 146 common frames omitted
app-1      | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
app-1      |    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
app-1      |    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]
app-1      |    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542) ~[na:na]
app-1      |    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[na:na]
app-1      |    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
app-1      |    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
app-1      |    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:153) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
app-1      |    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
app-1      |    ... 149 common frames omitted

Here is my docker-compose.yml:
version: '3.7'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file: ./.env
    ports:
      - $SPRING_LOCAL_PORT:$SPRING_DOCKER_PORT
    depends_on:
      mysqldb:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      - MYSQLDB_DOCKER_PORT=${MYSQLDB_DOCKER_PORT}
      - MYSQLDB_USER=${MYSQLDB_USER}
      - MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQLDB_DATABASE=${MYSQLDB_DATABASE}
      - JWT_SECRET=${JWT_SECRET}
      - JWT_EXPIRATION=${JWT_EXPIRATION}
    networks:
      - springboot-mysql-network
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:8.0.33
    env_file: ./.env
    ports:
      - $MYSQLDB_LOCAL_PORT:$MYSQLDB_DOCKER_PORT
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQLDB_DATABASE}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - springboot-mysql-network
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      retries: 10
      interval: 3s
      timeout: 30s
volumes:
  mysql-data:
networks:
  springboot-mysql-network:
    name: springboot-mysql-network

application.properties:
spring.application.name=AuthAPI
jwt.secret=${JWT_SECRET}
jwt.expiration=${JWT_EXPIRATION}
spring.jpa.database=mysql
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:${MYSQLDB_DOCKER_PORT}/${MYSQLDB_DATABASE}?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
spring.datasource.username=${MYSQLDB_USER}
spring.datasource.password=${MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.sql.init.mode=always
#spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
#spring.datasource.hikari.allow-pool-suspension=true

dockerfile:
FROM maven:3.8.3-openjdk-17 AS build
COPY src /home/app/src
COPY pom.xml /home/app
RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml clean package
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/home/app/target/AuthAPI-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]

.env:
MYSQLDB_USER=root
MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
MYSQLDB_DATABASE=connectDB
MYSQLDB_LOCAL_PORT=3307
MYSQLDB_DOCKER_PORT=3306

SPRING_LOCAL_PORT=8080
SPRING_DOCKER_PORT=8080

JWT_SECRET=your_secret_key
JWT_EXPIRATION=3600000

I am not able to identify how to fix this.
I have tried several Stack Overflow answers on similar issues, like

adding a platform tag in docker-compose.
Changing the mysql version in docker compose.

It seems that still my application container having hard time connecting with MySQL DB. I have been stuck around this for around 1 day now. Any help here will be appreciated.

Your database is not running on localhost. Localhost is the container with Spring Boot, if you want to connect to the MySQL database, you need to specify mysqldb as a host name in the JDBC URL in spring.datasource.url.

Thanks a lot to Mark for his observation. You saved my day!
I had to change "localhost" to "mysqldb" inside application.properties.
Also, I was using MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD as password, turns out default password was "root" for user "root".
When I faced error saying my user table doesn't exist, then had to specifically add spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update to tell spring to create table if not exist.

Make sure that all your settings are correct. I've got the same error message simply because I had a typo in the database name of the jdbc URL.
